# Change default 0.0.0.0 from docker to specific

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've managed to run my docker container installing php / composer / phpmyadmin.

But as a result for example phpmyadmin is accessible through the url : http://0.0.0.0:8080/

How can I change the default 0.0.0.0 by something with more sense like http://myapp:8080

I guess I have to add something into my hosts; but I also guess I have to update my docker so he knew he has to read it.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  symfony:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: project-manager
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - db
```

Comment: You wouldn't usually connect to 0.0.0.0; it's a special IP address that means "_listen on_ all interfaces".  You should be able to use your host's IP address instead, and giving that a different name would involve configuring a DNS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually 127.0.0.1 already respond as 0.0.0.0 listen to everything so as we just have to setup in the host what we need as usual. `127.0.0.1 myapp`